# Error: Get net::ERR_INVALID_URL Angular 13

Tags: angular

I'm loading products from server to Angular.And the imagepaths/images are attached with the products.The images are present at server port `localhost:3000`.And the path for images is `./assets/imagename`.But the images are not visible and the console shows me the **following error**

[image]

**Custom Pipe for safe url and Domsanitizer**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeurl',
})
export class SafeurlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(html: any) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(html);
  }
```

**ngOnInit Getting all the products from server**

```
results?: Book[];

 ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getallbooks().subscribe((data: Book[]) => {
      this.results = data;
      console.log(this.results);
    });
}
```

**html code.I tried with both `data:image/jpg;base64` and `data:image/png;base64` but the results are same**

```
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let result of results">
      <div class="blog-card spring-fever" style="padding: 0.5rem; z-index: 100">
        <div >
          <img
            class="image"
            [src]="'data:image/png;base64,' +'http://localhost:3000/'+result.coverimage | safeurl"
            alt=""
            height="400px"
            width="250px"
            style="border: 1px solid red"
          />
        </div>
```

**The error still remain even if I don't use `http://localhost:3000/` in `src`**

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your URL is not correct. You currently have:

`data:image/png;base64.http://localhost` etc...

This is not a valid http format.

Can you verify this theory by hard-coding a test URL in the source ?

If it works it will allow us to validate that it is just a question of writing the URL.

```
https://localhost:3000/image/assets/image.png
```

Comment: What would be the correct url?Any example for correct http formate...

Comment: I picked a random image from google,and copied the address,and paste in in source.And that random image is displaying.I searched some stackoverflow answers,and everyone is using the same formate  that I'm using.

Comment: `'https://localhost:3000/image/assets/image.png'`

Comment: Here : `[src]="'data:image/png;base64,' +'http://localhost:3000/'+result.coverimage | safeurl"`:

Comment: No brother my mistake I didn't mean that. I was trying to say how can I make my url correct according to the example `localhost:3000/image/assets/image.png `.

Comment: As I already told you that I searched the internet and everyone is using the same format that I'm using.

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other :

When you look for a cat image on the internet: you go to: `https://i.notretemps.com/1400x787/smart/2021/05/03/trois-facons-de-distraire-votre-chat-a- the-house.jpeg` right?

You don't go to 'chat.png/https://inotretemps.com'

Your error message tells you that your URL is invalid. I think that in your code you make a concatenation which explains this error... it is more or less the comma `,` in  the URL which seems to me to indicate it...

Comment: I'm just using concatenation in the url passing in source.You can validate the above code I uploaded.

Comment: You can see very easily if I'm totally wrong by replacing that `[src]="'data:image/png;base64,' +'http://localhost:3000/'+result.coverimage | safeurl"` with that `[src]="https://i.notretemps.com/1400x787/smart/2021/05/03/trois-facons-de-distraire-votre-chat-a- the-house.jpeg"` 
If you don't have the same error message and a picture of a little kitten, it's because it wasn't a bad idea.

Comment: your link is giving error. Also I tried by removing `,` after `base64` but the error is still there.And when I used your link wiht `src` instead of `[src]`, it gives the same url error that I'm facing

Comment: my bad, the right URL is : `https://i.notretemps.com/1400x787/smart/2021/05/03/trois-facons-de-distraire-votre-chat-a-la-maison.jpeg`v

Comment: This url is also giving error,it fills the vs code terminal with red lines and stopes the angular server.But when I used the url with `src` instead of `[src]`,you cat is visible

Comment: But how this is going to solve my URL.I got your point it's about concatenation and `,`.But already tried by removing `,`, and there seem to be only single comma in my URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use pipe in component.ts

**.component.ts**

```
constructor(...
            private safeurlPipe: SafeurlPipe) {
}

genImageUrl(coverimage: any): SafeResourceUrl {
    const safeResourceUrl = this.safeurlPipe.transform('data:image/png;base64,http://localhost:3000/' + coverimage);
    return safeResourceUrl;
}
```

**.component.html**

```
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let result of results">
  <div class="blog-card spring-fever" style="padding: 0.5rem; z-index: 100">
    <div *ngIf="image">
      <img
        class="image"
        [src]="genImageUrl(result.coverimage)"
        alt=""
        height="400px"
        width="250px"
        style="border: 1px solid red"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: with a blank screen I'm getting this error in console `core.mjs:6495 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[SafeurlPipe -> SafeurlPipe -> SafeurlPipe]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for SafeurlPipe!`

Comment: Did  you add `SafeurlPipe` in `providers` in `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: `providers: [SafeurlPipe],`. I have added now the error is gone.The products are coming but they are like glass and nothing visible on them.And network shows there is no image received

Comment: a dive was making issue,now the data is coming and visible but console shows this error for images `unsafe:data:image/png;base64,SafeValue must use [property]=binding: http://localhost:3000/./assets/7990d50b51.png (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss):1          GET unsafe:data:image/png;base64,SafeValue must use [property]=binding: http://localhost:3000/./assets/7990d50b51.png (see https://g.co/ng/security net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`. Even if I use `[src]="genImageUrl(result.coverimage) | safeurl"` , it shows same error

Comment: Try this, put whole string url to transform function  `this.safeurlPipe.transform('data:image/png;base64,http://localhost:3000/' + coverimage);`

Comment: I'm getting this at `return ` statment `Type 'SafeResourceUrl' is not assignable to type 'string'`. I tried by replacing `: string` with `:SafeResourceUrl`, but it's giving error `security 404 text/htm`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, just change return type from `string` to  `SafeResourceUrl` and it'll fixed.

Comment: no it's showing error `SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20data:image/png;base64,http://localhost:3000/assets/7990d50b51.png%20(see%20https://g.co/ng/security#xss):1          GET http://localhost:4200/SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20data:image/png;base64,http://localhost:3000/assets/7990d50b51.png%20(see%20https://g.co/ng/security 404 (Not Found)` in console and in network `name:security status:404 type:text/html`

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dj4tuy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have to paste that `base64Content` in my code as well?what that content actually is?I have to put my `localhost:3000` here...

Comment: I did it like this `base64Content='http://localhost:3000/'` and then called it as like in stackblitz example.Ok first it does not make any difference if I save url in a variable and call it or I simply past the url directly.The error is still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247169/discussion-between-paranaaan-and-m-nouman).

Answer (score 0):

**So in my case** I had a  list of books and each book has path for its image. I was using `ngFor` and set the image `src` with the path. That is the right way. But the images were not visible and Network was showing images as `text/html` type. The actual issue here was not the `type`,the actual issue was in my `URL`.I had a folder in NestJs server by the name of `assets`,that is preset at `root`, and I had set the path for the images(in NestJs file upload code), like this `./assets/`. That is also the correct way to set the destination folder.I was able to see the images at browser like this `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`,and that means my server configured to server/serve my images over root URL that's why I  can access them `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`. But my api was returning images in a format that contains `./assets/` in the URL. So with the following code

```
<div *ngIf="result.coverimage">
          <img
            class="image"
            [src]="'data:image/png;base64,' +'http://localhost:3000/'+result.coverimage | safeurl"
            alt=""
            height="400px"
            width="250px"
            style="border: 1px solid red"
          />
        </div>
```

I am assuming that I'm hitting the Url like this  `http:localhost:3000/imagename.png`. But actually Angular was seeing the URL like this `http:localhost:3000/./assets/imagename.png`. And **this is note the correct URL Format**. Urls don't work with `.` or `,`.Also becasue my server is configured at root, this url`http;//localhost:3000/assets/imagename.png` is also wrong.And `root` means that, whatever the thing is set at `root`, that is directly access able after your server's port number. Example `http://localhost:YourServerPortNumber/TheThing_Set_at_Root`.

> **So the solution for this issue is the following**

```
src="http://localhost:3000/{{
              result.coverimage.replace('./assets/', '')
            }}"
```

With above `.replace('./assets/', '')` we are removing the `./assets/` and repalcing it with `''` empty space. So now URL is in this format`http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`.
Also I can remove `safeurl pipe` for now beacuse it is `localhost`,but in prodction mod I will be needing that pipe. And It might happen that even with localhost somebody might need the pipe.

**I hope I understood the things myself correctly and explained them correctly**